# How to display tweets and retweets combinely from laravel controller in the view file..?

Tags: php, laravel, twitter, eloquent

I was creating a clone of laravel and had reached the point where tweets of user and his followers are displayed on the feed. But i need to display the retweets of the user_following in the feed as well along with the tweets.I have written a query for getting tweets collection in a $tweet variable and retweets collection in a $retweets variable. I need a way to join these collection somehow.
At the stage, i am displaying the tweets using foreach($tweets as $t) loop in the view file.
What can be done to display both tweets and retweets in one view randomly.
Below are the collection and the tweets display result shown
[collection of tweets and retweets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AF20o.png)
[Current result in localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq8zg.png)

Answer (score 1):

Laravel has a merge helper which returns the combined collection. It dwont affect the original collection try do the following

```
$tweet = new Collection(['tweets']);

$retweet = new Collection(['retweets']);

$merged = $tweet->merge($retweet);
```